# Cropping TIFF images based on imported KML file and tiling grid system of Sentinel 2 satellite imagery in Python

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, sentinel

I have some .jp2 formatted satellite images (ex. `T42UWF_20220714T063641_B04.jp2`) which have a resolution of (10980x10980).
I import Sentinel-2 Level 1C tiling grid system .KML file and manually created .KML file with coordinates of some pasture coordinates (created in Google Maps) and convert them all into the corresponding coordinate reference system (32642 in my case). When I crop area of interest, the result is just fine. As I expect it to be.

There are also some .tif formatted satellite images (named ex. `S2A_tile_20220714_42UWF_0_R10B04.tif`) which, interestingly, have a resolution of (11245x11248). The result is slightly different when I do the same steps with this image. I have to shift cropping coordinates slightly by x and y.

Completely newbie in this field. Working on the data I was provided. Am I doing something wrong? Does the tiling grid system of Sentinel-2 Level 1C apply to .tif formatted images?
Visited the official site of Sentinel 2. It is said that product files are provided in .jp2 format. So where do .tif files come from ?

Just in case, the tiling grid system of Sentinel-2 Level 1C can be found [here](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-2/data-products)

Comment: Not all satellite images are georeferenced the same. Also, they are acquired in different 'grids' with different resolutions. How much do you have to 'shift' them by?

Comment: 13 pixel by "x" axis and 9 by "y". Area of interest is a very small pasture with the size of 185x78